# Can not get widgets positioned in combi of GridLayout and BoxLayout using Kivy

Tags: kivy

I am trying to implement a fixed size UI consisting of 4 columns according to the structure below (see link "Wired frame"). At column 3 I got lost after hours of studying, looking at examples and a lot of trial and error. Who can help me? Below the kv content as well.
Thanks in advance.

[Wired frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpq89.png)

```
<IeditHome>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 4
        # 1st Column
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: .7,.7,.7
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                    BorderImage:
                        source: 'C:/images/border.png'
                        border: (2,2,2,2)
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                text: '1'
                size_hint: None, None
                height: 120
                width: 25
                halign: 'right'
                valign: 'middle'
                color: .4,.4,.4,1

                # Add 4 Label bloks of the same.
                # Re-engineer duplicated stuff later...

        # 2nd Column
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Image:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: .7,.7,.7
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                    BorderImage:
                        source: 'C:/images/border.png'
                        border: (2,1,1,2)
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                size: 240, 120
                source: 'C:/temp/Object1.png'

                # Add 4 image bloks of the same.
                # Re-engineer duplicated stuff later...

        # 3rd Column   
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: .7,.7,.7
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                text: 'This is the titel'
            Image:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: .7,.7,.7
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                    BorderImage:
                        source: 'C:/images/border.png'
                        border: (2,1,1,2)
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                size: 300, 200
                source: 'C:/temp/MediumImage.png'
            Image:
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgb: .7,.7,.7
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                    BorderImage:
                        source: 'C:/images/border.png'
                        border: (2,1,1,2)
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                size: 500, 300
                source: 'C:/temp/LargeImage.png'

    ActionBar:
        pos: 0, 600
        font_size: 16
        size: 1200, 40
        # background color in Kivy acts as a tint and not just a solid color.
        # set a pure white background image first.
        background_image: 'C:/images/white-bg.png'
        background_color: .2,.6,.7,1
        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
                size: 1200, 40
                font_size: 16
                title: 'Ieditor'
                with_previous: False
            ActionOverflow:
            ActionButton:
                icon: 'C:/images/butt_prev.png'
            ActionButton:
                icon: 'C:/images/butt_next.png'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small **working** example of the 3rd column should look like (The A class)

```
Builder.load_string("""

<InputBar@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        text: 'some text'
    TextInput:
        text: 'input?'
    Label:
        text: 'some text2'
    TextInput:
        text: 'input2?'
<A>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'some title'
    InputBar:
        id: input1
    InputBar:
        id: input2
    InputBar:
        id: input3
    InputBar:
        id: input4
    Label:
        text: 'some title2'
    InputBar:
        id: input5
    InputBar:
        id: input6
    InputBar:
        id: input7
    InputBar:
        id: input8
    InputBar:
        id: input9
""")

class A(BoxLayout):
    pass


class VApp(App):

    def build(self):


        return A()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    VApp().run()
```

Just place it inside your big example I guess.